# Can i install OpenSearch without using Docker on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, magento, magento2, opensearch

So i was looking to install OpenSearch for my localhost Magento2 installation, but i could only find install methods for using Docker..

I'm not using Docker for a few reasons, that have to do with the company i'm at right now, but i would really like to just install OpenSearch on my own computer locally, and run it locally, not using other programs like Docker, is that even possible?

BTW; i'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and Magento 2.4.6 (if thats even important to know lol)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

OpenSearch [documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/install-and-configure/install-opensearch/index/) provides at least a couple ways to install it without docker. I will list two of the methods below to avoid copy pasting whole documentation.

### Using [tarball](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/install-and-configure/install-opensearch/tar/) (aka download archive, extract it and run)

**Step 1: Download and unpack OpenSearch**

```
# x64
wget https://artifacts.opensearch.org/releases/bundle/opensearch/2.7.0/opensearch-2.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz

# ARM64
wget https://artifacts.opensearch.org/releases/bundle/opensearch/2.7.0/opensearch-2.7.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
```

Extract the contents of the tarball.

```
# x64
tar -xvf opensearch-2.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
   
# ARM64
tar -xvf opensearch-2.7.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
```

**Step 2: Configure important system settings**

Disable memory paging and swapping performance on the host to improve performance.

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Increase the number of memory maps available to OpenSearch.

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf

# Add a line to define the desired value
# or change the value if the key exists,
# and then save your changes.
vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Reload the kernel parameters using sysctl and verify that the change was applied by checking the value

```
sudo sysctl -p
cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

**Step 3: Run OpenSearch**

```
cd /path/to/opensearch-2.7.0
./opensearch-tar-install.sh
```

---

### From an APT repository

Install the necessary packages.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install lsb-release ca-certificates curl gnupg2
```

Import the public GPG key. This key is used to verify that the APT repository is signed.

```
 curl -o- https://artifacts.opensearch.org/publickeys/opensearch.pgp | sudo gpg --dearmor --batch --yes -o /usr/share/keyrings/opensearch-keyring
```

Create an APT repository for OpenSearch:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/opensearch-keyring] https://artifacts.opensearch.org/releases/bundle/opensearch/2.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opensearch-2.x.list
```

Verify that the repository was created successfully.

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

With the repository information added, list all available versions of OpenSearch:

```
sudo apt list -a opensearch
```

Choose the version of OpenSearch you want to install:

```
sudo apt-get install opensearch
```

To install a specific version of OpenSearch:

```
# Specify the version manually using opensearch=<version>
sudo apt-get install opensearch=2.7.0
```

Once complete, enable OpenSearch.

```
 sudo systemctl enable opensearch
```

Start OpenSearch.

```
 sudo systemctl start opensearch
 sudo systemctl status opensearch
```

---

### To verify that OpenSearch installed correctly.

Send a request to port 9200:

```
curl -X GET https://localhost:9200 -u 'admin:admin' --insecure
```

You should get a response that looks like this:

```
 {
    "name" : "hostname",
    "cluster_name" : "opensearch",
    "cluster_uuid" : "6XNc9m2gTUSIoKDqJit0PA",
    "version" : {
       "distribution" : "opensearch",
       "number" : <version>,
       "build_type" : <build-type>,
       "build_hash" : <build-hash>,
       "build_date" : <build-date>,
       "build_snapshot" : false,
       "lucene_version" : <lucene-version>,
       "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.10.0",
       "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
    },
    "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Magento2 latest version supports the 2.5.0 version only, so I will be sharing the steps to install that from the APT repository directly. In this all the steps are copied from the [official documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/install-and-configure/install-opensearch/debian/#install-opensearch-from-an-apt-repository):

**Install OpenSearch from an APT repository**

APT, the primary package management tool for Debian–based operating systems, allows you to download and install the Debian package from the APT repository.

**Step 1:** Install the necessary packages.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install lsb-release ca-certificates curl gnupg2
```

**Step 2:** Import the public GPG key. This key is used to verify that the APT repository is signed.

```
 curl -o- https://artifacts.opensearch.org/publickeys/opensearch.pgp | sudo gpg --dearmor --batch --yes -o /usr/share/keyrings/opensearch-keyring
```

**Step 3:** Create an APT repository for OpenSearch:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/opensearch-keyring] https://artifacts.opensearch.org/releases/bundle/opensearch/2.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opensearch-2.x.list
```

**Step 4:** Verify that the repository was created successfully.

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

**Step 5:** With the repository information added, list all available versions of OpenSearch:

```
sudo apt list -a opensearch
```

**Step 6:** Choose the version of OpenSearch you want to install:

**Step 6.1 :** Unless otherwise indicated, the latest available version of OpenSearch is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install opensearch
```

**Step 6.2 :** To install a specific version of OpenSearch:

```
Specify the version manually using opensearch=<version>
Example: sudo apt-get install opensearch=2.5.0
```

**Once complete, enable OpenSearch.**

```
 sudo systemctl enable opensearch
```

**Start OpenSearch.**

```
 sudo systemctl start opensearch
```

**Verify that OpenSearch launched correctly.**

```
 sudo systemctl status opensearch
```

**Test OpenSearch**

```
 curl -X GET https://localhost:9200 -u 'admin:admin' --insecure
You should get a response that looks like this:

 {
    "name":"hostname",
    "cluster_name":"opensearch",
    "cluster_uuid":"QqgpHCbnSRKcPAizqjvoOw",
    "version":{
       "distribution":"opensearch",
       "number":<version>,
       "build_type":<build-type>,
       "build_hash":<build-hash>,
       "build_date":<build-date>,
       "build_snapshot":false,
       "lucene_version":<lucene-version>,
       "minimum_wire_compatibility_version":"7.10.0",
       "minimum_index_compatibility_version":"7.0.0"
    },
    "tagline":"The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
 }
```

**Query the plugins endpoint:**

```
 curl -X GET https://localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v -u 'admin:admin' --insecure
    
The response should look like this:

    name      component                           version
    hostname opensearch-alerting                  2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-anomaly-detection         2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-asynchronous-search       2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-cross-cluster-replication 2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-geospatial                2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-index-management          2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-job-scheduler             2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-knn                       2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-ml                        2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-neural-search             2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-notifications             2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-notifications-core        2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-observability             2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-performance-analyzer      2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-reports-scheduler         2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-security                  2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-security-analytics        2.5.0.0
    hostname opensearch-sql                       2.5.0.0
```